# Chunked transfer contents of block device over bad network

Tags: rsync, block-device

`/dev/sda` is the only disk on system. I want to save it to a raw image on another server. I can't do it in one shot, because network disconnects often.

Is it possible with e.g. torrent?

Comment: You should boot from USB/CD to do anything like this and not use `/dev/sda` until the transfer is done.

Comment: I don't have the problem reading /dev/sda or mounting it readonly. When I try to copy /dev/sda over ssh, it disconnects in the middle of the process due to network problems.

Comment: Use an SFTP client that is able to reconnect and resume transfers automatically like `lftp`.

Comment: Sftp can't resume reading block device, because its reported size is always zero

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way to do this is to resume transfer from where it left off.

```
#!/bin/bash

source_disk=/dev/sda
host=1.2.3.4
host_image=/foo/bar.img

bytes_transferred() {
  if ! ssh "$host" "test -e '$host_image'"; then
    echo 0
    return
  fi
  ssh "$host" "stat '%s' '$host_image'"
}
bytes_total() {
  echo $(( $(blockdev --getsz $source_disk) * 512 ))
}

while (( $(bytes_transferred) < $(bytes_total) )); do
  ( dd bs=1 skip=$(bytes_transferred) count=0 2>/dev/null && cat ) < $source_disk | ssh "$host" "cat >> '$host_image'"
done
```

This is untested, but should work. It basically continues looping while the size of the destination file is less than the size of the local disk. Each time the loop restarts, it starts the transfer from from where it left off previously

Comment: Started the fixed script inside `screen`.